# Why does this not disprove that the set of all rational numbers is countable?

Tags: infinity, rational-numbers, natural-numbers

I've seen [this snake diagonal proof](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Arqu5.png) and I can kind of understand the logic and how equivalent fractions eventually cancel out. However, why would something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qogsi.png) not disprove that the set of rational numbers is countable? Since (N/(N + 1)) will never create repeat/equivalent fractions and no fractions of that form will ever equal 1/3, how is the set of rationals countable? Shouldn't the cardinality be at least one greater than that of the naturals (infinitely more fractions that don't follow (N/(N+1)) that I could include)?

Comment: Showing countability means an injection from a set to $\mathbb{N}$, showing equality of cardinality requires a bijection between sets. Your function $f(n) = \frac{n}{n+1}$ is not a bijection.

Comment: "cardinality... at least one greater than that of the naturals": infinite cardinalities behave much differently from finite cardinalities.  Look up Hilbert's hotel for some examples of this.

Comment: Enumerability means that you **could** put the elements of the set in order. And you can with your example: just shift everything down by one and fit in $1/3$ at the top. Your argument is like claiming that the natural numbers themselves are not countable because $1$ is missing from the RHS of the mapping $1\to2,2\to3,3\to4,\ldots$

Comment: Suffices to find an injection $\mathbb Q\to\mathbb N$ and you will have proved countability.

Comment: @Jam That makes sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Since the set of natural numbers is infinite, adding a single extra fraction doesn't change its cardinality. The set of rational numbers is indeed countable, and if you look at one of the standard enumerations, you get that the subsequence using the fractions that you considered go $1/2, 1/3, 2/3, 3/4, 4/5, 5/6, ...$ See the Stern-Brocot tree and the Calkin-Wilf tree for two simple bijections.